# Не обновляется время в классе, вызваном циклом Java

Tags: java, время, циклы

Здравствуйте.
При вызове `(int) (System.currentTimeMillis());` напрямую из цикла - при каждой итерации получается новое значение, но при вызове этой же функции в классе, вызванном этим же циклом - значение не меняется:

```
private static void updateGame () {

    GameTime Time = new GameTime (null);

    while (true) {

        Time = new GameTime (Time);

        if (Time != null) {

            System.out.println (Time.hours + ":" + Time.minutes);

        }

    }

}
import java.util.Date;


public class GameTime {

    Settings settings = new Settings ();
    int gameSpeed = settings.gameSpeed ();

    static int hours, minutes;
    static int timestamp = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static int hours () {

        return hours;

    }

    public static int minutes () {

        return minutes;

    }

    public static int timestamp () {

        return timestamp;

    }

    GameTime(GameTime Time) {

            System.out.println (Time.timestamp + "; " + timestamp);

        if (Time == null) {

            this.hours = 06;
            this.minutes = 00;

        } else {

            if (Time.timestamp + gameSpeed >= timestamp) {

                this.minutes += 1;

            }

            if (this.minutes >= 60) {

                this.minutes = 00;
                this.hours += 1;

            }

            if (this.hours >= 24) {

                this.hours = 00;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтоб при каждой итерации цикла метод `GameTime.timestamp ()` принимал новое значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите модификатор `static` у поля `timestamp`, а то оно у вас одно на все классы и инициализируется в момент объявление класса, а не создания экземпляра.

Comment: Вам надо определиться с логикой работы вашей программы. Либо вы используете статические члены и тогда не инстанцируете объект, либо убираете модификторы `static` и работаете с экземплярами.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at samyred.finefishing.GameTime.<init>(GameTime.java:34)
 at samyred.finefishing.Main.updateGame(Main.java:41)
 at samyred.finefishing.Main.main(Main.java:33)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds). 34-я строка: System.out.println (Time.timestamp + "; " + timestamp); (Я убрал static, но получилось это)